# Is there a word like 'twain' that means 'three'?

Tags: single-word-requests

I have a list of three items, and I'd like to say the equivalent of "never the twain shall meet." Is there a word meaning "three" that I could substitute for "twain"? "None of them will ever meet" works, but doesn't have quite the same quaintness. I know that "twain" comes from the Anglo-Saxon "twengen," and was thinking that maybe the word I'm looking for could come from "threo/thrim/thrie" perhaps.
Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps *trio* would fit?  Wrong language of origin, but otherwise seems okay.

Comment: According to google, twain stands for "archaic term for two", not three, [Source](https://www.google.com/search?q=twain+definition). What definition are you going off of?

Comment: Consider this question here, sorta different usage, but they have a few good suggestions like just "three" or "trine".https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/54589/is-there-a-similar-word-to-twain-but-meaning-three-instead-of-two

Comment: Welcome to English Language and Usage, If you get adventurous, you could try "some invention like: "Never the three'uns 'll meet.. Good Luck